# can i add to checkedListBox a name + date ? (c#)

Tags: c#, datetimepicker, checkedlistbox

ok , last try :)
i have a small form that a user have to fill(name, date, etc), when he click "send"
i want that his name together with the date (the user entring the date in DateTimePicker format)will show up in the CheckedListBox as 1 item (example="gil 17/12/2011")
is it possible at all ?

Comment: What do you mean "in one line"?

Comment: Still no idea what you mean. Same item? Item of what?

Comment: sorry, i have a bad english...

Comment: i try again - i have a checkedListBox, when i add an item , is it possible to add (along with the item's name) a date from dateTimePicker ?

Comment: @Gil - the problem isn't your English, but that you are not giving enough detail. You need to explain a lot more about what you are doing, what you are trying to do and what is not working. יותר מידע

Comment: @Gil - A word here and there doesn't hurt, but not the whole thing...

Comment: i edit it as mutch as i could, hope it's enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. The trick here is to know that ListBox (and CheckedListBox) contain a list of `Object`s. It uses the `ToString` method of those objects to display. All you have to do is populate the list with your own type which has a `ToString` override.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Form1 : Form
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "Name", Location = new Point(10, 10), AutoSize = true });
        Controls.Add(new TextBox { Name = "Name", Location = new Point(60, 10) });
        Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "Date", Location = new Point(10, 40), AutoSize = true });
        Controls.Add(new DateTimePicker { Name = "Date", Location = new Point(60, 40) });
        Controls.Add(new Button { Name = "Submit", Text = "Submit", Location = new Point(10, 70) });
        Controls.Add(new CheckedListBox { Name = "List", Location = new Point(10, 100), Size = new Size(ClientSize.Width - 20, ClientSize.Height - 100 - 10) });
        Controls["Submit"].Click += (s, e) =>
                (Controls["List"] as CheckedListBox).Items.Add(new MyItem { Name = Controls["Name"].Text, Date = (Controls["Date"] as DateTimePicker).Value });
    }
}

public class MyItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} {1}", Name, Date);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without some effort, No, it's not possible, but you can implement that by yourself. Have a look at [Editable ListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/LeerGridView.aspx) and [In-place editing of ListView subitems](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ListViewCellEditors.aspx).